# jquery turn array to string in order to appendTo() it

Tags: jquery, arrays, join, append

I've got a jquery array[] containing divs and tables.
I created this array by selecting objects from a common class

```
$(".class").children('div,table')
```

I need to appendTo() them in an other div.
What is the best way to do that? I was thinking about array.join() them but when I do it I get an error saying `array.join is not a function.` But I'm quite sure array is an array because when I console.log() it I get:

> init(12) [div#title-1448668226._SK_font_title_3.textBlock, table,
>   table, table, table, table, table, table, table,
>   div#title-1453122599._SK_font_title_3.textBlock, table, table,
>   prevObject: init(22), context: document]0:
>   div#title-1448668226._SK_font_title_3.textBlock1: table2: table3:
>   table4: table5: table6: table7: table8: table9:
>   div#title-1453122599._SK_font_title_3.textBlock10: table11:
>   tablecontext: documentlength: 12prevObject:
>   init(22) [div#title-202747427._SK_font_title_3.textBlock, table,
>   table, table, table, table, table, table, table, table,
>   div#title-1448668226._SK_font_title_3.textBlock, table, table, table,
>   table, table, table, table, table,
>   div#title-1453122599._SK_font_title_3.textBlock, table, table,
>   prevObject: init(1), context: document]**proto**: Object(0)

Am I missing something ? Is join() and appendTo() the best way to make content 'travelling' ?

Thanks !

Comment: How did you generate the array of divs? Can you add that code to your question? This will help us be sure that it's an array of jQuery objects that you're working with.

Comment: @AJFerron thanks it's updated

Comment: Do you want to move the content to the new div or do you want to create a copy there?

Comment: @PeterKA I want to move all the content (with html entities included) into a new div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.children()` returns an array of jQuery objects, and these can be appended directly to another element using `.append()` or `.appendTo()`.

```
$(".class").children('div,table').appendTo( $('div.myclass') )
```

This will append all of the selected elements to a div with the class `myclass`

Comment: Works fine.. needed a bit of time to solve issues but that was a "break;" issue. Nothing to do with your code. It works fine. thanks =) !